# RequestParameter and view_email_url

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to send extra parameters to view_email_url and then pick them up and use them on the web version of the email? I would like to do this so I can perform different actions, such as display a pop up or play a video.

It should be as simple as the code below, but unfortunately RequestParameter doesn't seem to work on the VAWP:

```
%%[

if _MessageContext == "VAWP" then
set @parameter = RequestParameter("parameter")

]%%

<span>The parameter is: %%=v(@parameter)=%%</span>

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should be able to just use "parameter" as a personalization string instead of requesting a parameter. From my understanding, the info passed via parameter into an ET landing page via the Microsite_URL ampscript (default for VAWP) is then used in same reference as attributes in a list or DE.

SO basically, if that theory is correct, below should work:

```
%%[

if _MessageContext == "VAWP" then
set @parameter = [parameter]

]%%

<span>The parameter is: %%=v(@parameter)=%%</span>

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: I need to be able to have multiple view_email_urls, with different parameters so this doesn't work. The normal VAWP we have in the bottom of the email should function differently than some other URL such as play video.